# Long time opening connections to the Oracle database

Tags: oracle, docker, .net-core, networking, docker-compose

I am using ASP.NET for RestApi with connection to Oracle database on external server. My app is hosting on Linux server in Docker containers. Database Oracle hosting on Windows Server 2012. All Servers is located on local corporation network.

After deploy on Production i send GET request method to authenticate and method work correctly i am received what i want. But after one hour of nonaction i send again this GET request method my app become in long loading state and response comes after 15 minutes. But i am expecting that response will come maximum in 5 sec.

Also i use DI and register connection to Database as Scoped

Specification:

- OS: Linux x86-64 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- App: .NET 8 with EF Core
- Container: Docker, Docker Compose
- Database: Oracle 19

I found that long loading starts when the application wants to open a connection to the database

Thats what i logged

```
[07:14:01 DBG] Created DbConnection. (3ms). <s:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection>
[07:14:01 DBG] Opening connection to database '' on server 'MyDatabaseIp'. <s:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection>
[07:29:42 DBG] Opened connection to database '' on server 'MyDatabaseIp'. <s:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection>
```

How you can see it took near 15 minutes

This is my Connection String

`"MyDatabase": "Data Source=MyDatabaseIp:1521/User;Password=pass@Word; User ID=User; Persist Security Info=true"`

I was trying to turn on `KeepAlive=True` and `Pooling=true` but this nothing change my app still become in long loading state. Also tried to turn off pooling.

To fix this problem i have two options

1. Wait while i receive response
2. Restart Docker compose

Tried to reproduce on my local computer this problem and this never happened. In my opinion it looks like problems with network.